# Quarkus How to get all url query param?

Tags: rest, search, quarkus, query-string, quarkus-rest-client

I would like to get all query params from an URL but I can't use @QueryParam without specifying a name, since names of paramters are dynamic, I can have some params that start with same name : param_toto, param_tata, param_titi, etc.

```
@QueryParam("") Map<String, String> queryParams
```

I get this error : `RESTEASY003875: Unable to find a constructor that takes a String param or a valueOf() or fromString() method for javax.ws.rs.QueryParam("")`

Please not that I don't want to use : HttpServletRequest since is not support by Quarkus, and I need to add a dependecy, of corse vertx has it implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@Context UriInfo uriInfo` and call `uriInfo.getQueryParameters()`

Comment: Is there another solution to get a Map directly using something like @QueryParam("") in quarkus instead of UriInfo, please?

Comment: No, there is not